How do you find $f'(t,y(t))$ in the context of IVPs?
In the numerical methods class I am taking, IVPs are formulated as $y'=f(t,y(t))$. However, I do not understand how we differentiate $f(t,y(t))$. Here is an example of my confusion:
$f(t,y(t))=y(t)-t^2+1 \Rightarrow f'(t,y(t))=y(t)'-2t$
It seems as if we are differentiating with respect to both t and y, yet we are choosing which terms get differentiated by each variable. Perhaps instead of somehow differentiating both variables at once it is adding partial derivatives? I cannot find a well described way of calculating this derivative in the textbook I am following.

Note that $y = y(t),$ so we're just interpreting this as a total derivative and using the chain rule.

I see. Thank you.

$f'(t,y(t))$ isn't very good notation. $\frac{d}{dt} f(t,y(t))$, or maybe even $\frac{d}{dt} \bigl( f(t,y(t)) \bigr)$, would make the intended meaning much clearer.

Karl Heun in his exploration in 1900 used $Df$, also found are notations like $f^{[3]}$.

Have you worked with partial derivatives at this time? In conjunction with the chain rule? An answer can be given in terms of those concepts.
